# rgbdslam compiles but I get an error trying to run it

Tags: slam, navigation, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/jackson/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_s
Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_f
Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_b
[ 13%] Built target siftgpu_proj
[ 19%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_py
[ 34%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_lisp
[ 34%] Built target rgbdslam_gencpp
[ 34%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
[100%] Built target rgbdslam
```

Since the build gets to 100% I try

```
$ roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch
```

`[openni+rgbdslam.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rgbdslam] nor is [rgbdslam] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file`

How do I get past this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224309/rgbdslam-compiles-but-i-get-an-error-trying-to-run-it/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source your workspace once it was built?

try:

```
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xiongxiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26763/xiongxiong/) on 2016-05-17**:
thank you!!